# Customize the Bing Translator Web Widget

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, bing-translator-api

I'm trying to implement the [Bing Translator Web Widget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn355994.aspx) in my BigCommerce site.  The default widget is a bit clunky and doesn't fit in with my sites appearance.  Is there any way that I can mimic the Widgets functionality in a select list of languages?  Alternatively, little flags are always pleasant to the eye.

Microsoft gives more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx) but I'm unsure how to preserve the default features like having an admin sign in and improve the translation.